# Intermittent Runtime error :The ConnectionString property has not been initialized when using EF Core context. this error is occurring only some times

Tags: entity-framework, nuget, .net-6.0, dbcontext, sqlclient

Recently I upgraded my project to .Net 6, in order to change the runtime version of my Azure function to v4, as part of this I was facing an error while using System.Data.SqlClient, I changed that to Microosft.data.SqlClient. After these changes, I am seeing intermittent runtime exceptions in my code, when I am trying to connect to database using Entity Framework.Also, I upgraded Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore from 2.1.4 to 6.0.10

Code returning error (in bold)

```
public async Task<Common.Entities.Delivery> GetNotificationDeliveryByRequestIdClientId(string notificationRequestId,
            int clientId)
        {
            Common.Entities.Delivery deliveryContext = null;
            try
            {
                **deliveryContext = await (from delivery in _context.Delivery
                                         where delivery.NotificationRequestId == notificationRequestId
                                         where delivery.ClientId == clientId
                                         select delivery).FirstOrDefaultAsync();**

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogCritical(ex, $"{DeliveryComponent}.{nameof(GetNotificationDeliveryByRequestIdClientId)}.Exception");
            }

            return deliveryContext;
        }


DBContext class:

   public NotificationDeliveryRepository(NotificationsDeliveryContext deliveryContext)
        {
            _context = deliveryContext;
        }

        public NotificationDeliveryRepository(string deliverySqlConnStr, ILogger logger)
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<NotificationsDeliveryContext>().UseSqlServer(deliverySqlConnStr)
                .Options;
          
            _context = new NotificationsDeliveryContext(options);

            Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(logger));
        }
```

Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException","message":"The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.